# wpf binding nested list

Tags: wpf, list, data-binding, collections, nested-lists

I am trying to display this nested list flat in a listview.

For example if the EventItem has responses I need to repeat the event name x time per each reponse.  And each response with have 3 checkboxes associated.

What I am trying to do is in a list Display:

EventName ->  Response Option -> Check Boxes of Effort.

I don't want to use a tree, hence the list single line.  Any ideas?

UPDATE:

Lets say I have 2 events and event 1 has 2 options and event 2 as 3 options.  Each option will have 3 checkboxes.

How I am trying to display the data is like this:

```
Event 1         Response A       [X]   [ ]   [ ]
Event 1         Response B       [ ]   [X]   [X]
Event 2         Response A       [X]   [X]   [X]
Event 2         Response D       [ ]   [ ]   [X]
Event 2         Response E       [X]   [X]   [X]
```

With Response I need to repeat the event name.

```
public class EventItem: DataAttributeChecked
{
    public EventItem(int primaryKey, string value) : base(primaryKey, value)
    {
        ResponseOptions = new List<ResponseOption>();
    }

    public List<ResponseOption> ResponseOptions { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseOption: DataAttribute
{
    public ResponseOption(int primaryKey, string value, int eventId) : base(primaryKey, value)
    {
        _eventId = eventId;
        LevelOfEfforts = new List<DataAttributeChecked>();
    }

    public List<DataAttributeChecked> LevelOfEfforts { get; set; }

    private readonly int _eventId;

    public int EventId
    {
        get { return _eventId; }
    }
}

<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border Margin="3" CornerRadius="2" BorderBrush="CadetBlue" BorderThickness="1">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" />

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ResponseOption.Value}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>   
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                             ItemsSource="{Binding ResponseOptions.LevelOfEffort}" 
                             Name="lstOption" 
                             SelectionMode="Multiple" >

                        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            </Style>
                        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3,3,3,3">
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </StackPanel>

            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Hmm. I was going to suggest you override your ListBox's ItemsPanel to display its items horizontally... but I see you *are* doing that. What doesn't work, exactly?

Comment: I just updated the comment with a better description.

Comment: can you mention what's not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

If the list is nested, you have a tree,
for which you can use a HierarchicalDataTemplate
and display in a TreeView or nested ListViews.

If you want to view in a flat list,
have your ViewModel flatten the tree,
assuming you are using an MVVM pattern.

Comment: I am not using the MVVM pattern with this project.  How else can you flatten the view?  I just updated the original question.

Comment: By changing your design to MVVM :-)    One of the major points of MVVM is having the ability to decouple the design of the View and that of Model from each other by introducing the ViewModel.