# C# WPF ListView MVVM ObservableCollection inside of an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, observablecollection

I have an `ObservableCollection` of `Team` `(ObservableCollection<Team>)`. In my `Team` class I have an `ObservableCollection` of "Actor" (ObservableCollection). Now I want display the actors in a `Listview` in with mvvm pattern.

Anyone have a solution? I did not found anything on google to show the actors in my `Listview`.

Thanks in advance.

```
<Window x:Class="Room.Views.MainView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Room.Views"
    xmlns:localBind="clr-namespace:Room.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="" Height="300" Width="800">

<Window.DataContext>
    <localBind:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <ListView Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedActor}" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Id" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Niggname" Width="160" 
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: need c# code how you load your observable collections, definition of your classes... wpf is not sufficient

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you want to show the Actors of the selected Team in a second ListView, or do you want to have nested ListViews, i.e. an inner ListView (or better ListBox or ItemsControl) in a GridViewTemplateColumn?

Comment: I want to show all actors collected in the listview. 

@Frenchy
[GitHub s4rem-ex-room-tool](https://github.com/FazeDaFapper/s4rem-ex-room-tool)

Comment: as says Clemens, you dont say where you want your listview? it misses the design..

Comment: as i said i want all actors of all teams collected in one listview. Without an extra property.

Comment: The easiest but not the best way is using `IValueConverter` to merge the data. As for me, the best way is keep all Actors in one collection and filter it with `ICollectionView.Filter`.

Answer (score 0):

From this other [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544567/wpf-binding-nested-list):

> If the list is nested, you have a tree, for which you can use a
>   HierarchicalDataTemplate and display in a TreeView or nested
>   ListViews.
>
> If you want to view in a flat list, have your ViewModel flatten the
>   tree, assuming you are using an MVVM pattern.

Your listview is showing each individual `Team` as an item. Because you have nested collections (`Teams` is a collection of collections of `Actors`), your `Id` and `Name` bindings aren't binding to the `Actor` items but to the `Team` items.

My initial solution was to go deeper and put a `listview` inside of a `listview`

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListView Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Actors}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedActor}" >
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Id" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="160" 
                                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

with the following result:

### [image: First Solution Nested ListViews]

However, as you can see I can only select a `Team`. I *can* select an `Actor` within each list but this is not what you want (under running assumption you want a single list).

What was easier for me was to flatten the tree in C#. Assuming that I have a flat list of actors (regardless of team) I can do this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AllActors}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedActor}" >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Id" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="160" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

with the following result:
[image: Second Solution Flattened List]

How you decide to flatten the list is up to you. Make sure to implement INPC on the `Team` class as well since modifying a `Team` inside an `ObservableCollection<Team>` won't tell the collection to update the binding without INPC.

If you are strictly following MVVM, I would possibly recommend creating some `Dependency Property`s in your control's code behind and flatten the list there.

My rationale is that this operation is purely cosmetic. We aren't performing business logic or changing data when we flatten the list; we are only prepping it for how we want to *view* it. So, we shall put the code to that in the code-behind as opposed to the VM. This is a bit more difficult though since now you have to make sure you bind correctly from VM <-> DP <-> Control as opposed to VM <-> Control.